# Reflect points on an image chart in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I need help, I am preparing for an engineering App, & in this App I need to reflect the result of the calculation on a chart, the chart is a photo... how can manage to let my flutter App understand that the axis points in the image chart are coordinates & how to reflect a point on the chart image[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `"to reflect a point on the chart image"`?

Comment: it is just I need to show the calculated point as a circuit on the chart to till the user that the point is here

Comment: use `CustomPaint` widget then - it gives you a full control and lets you draw whatever you want

Comment: the main issue is how can I tell the App that the numbers in the horizontal & vertical access are the coordinates that the app needs to determine the point?

Comment: you have to calculate the point somehow, as I can see you have some logarithmic X axis - you have to know how those points are distributed

Comment: this is what I am trying to do... I am not sure how but your idea to use customPaint widget might work if I can find a package that can make a logarithmic axis, then maybe I can make both above each other

Comment: this is where [dart:math](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-math/dart-math-library.html) can help you: it has `log()` method

Comment: i am not sure about it, I guess I need something like fl_chart package

Comment: the Idea is the cart is an image so flutter will not be able to determine the axis points, so I think I need to make another (let us say) Layer with the axis scales matching the image scale, then the point will be reflected based on the chart package. and overall it will appear that the point is reflected on the image.